# I'd like to know how to use @Htmlhelper to pass values to controller while using Bootstrap framework to design my button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

This is a jump I made using the `ActionLink` in `@Htmlhelper`, but my Bootstrap button design turned out like this:

[image: @HTMLAction() button]

`@HTMLAction()` button code is:

```
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
             <span class="icon text-white-50">
                   <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
             </span>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditForm", "Dashboard", new { id = Model.FormId })
      </button>
```

When I jump with the `<a>` tag it renders this effect:

[image: tag]

HTML markup is:

```
    <button href="/Dashboard/EditForm" class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
          <span class="icon text-white-50">
                  <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
          </span>
                    <span class="text" id="Edit">Edit</span>
    </button>
```

While I use `Htmlhelper` to pass values while jumping, I can't achieve such a normal effect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<button href="/Dashboard/EditForm" class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
    <span class="icon text-white-50">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
    </span>

    <a class="text" href="@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditForm", "Dashboard", new { id = Model.FormId })" id="Edit">Edit</a>
</button>
```